# Turnkey QR code scanner that is easy script custom actions

Tags: android, ios, ipad, qr-code, tablet

Say I have a user ID embedded into a QR code. The user presents their QR code to a QR reader, which 1) scans the code, 2) grabs the ID, 3) generates a 2nd ID, 4) then makes a REST API call to a remote web service passing both ID values and 5) checking for a response.

Is there a QR code reader app that can be easily scripted/extended to handle steps 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5? Or, is this something that I would have to write myself using a QR library for iOS/Android/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The barcode scanner app from google zxing can read and return qr code data from an intent.